# getting id when the email is opened

Tags: php, get

I have a text editor where I have the following email content ready and when the candidate apply for a job then they get that email.

Email template content:

```
Candidate ID Number [%candidate_ID%]

Dear [%First_Name%]

..........
...........

Regards,
Admin
```

Email template content finished

Now when someone apply for a job he/she gets an email with above info.Now I am trying to get that id when the email is opened for the first time.So what I am doing is inserting a piece of code like

```
<img src="getId.php?id=[%candidate_ID%]">
```

at the end of the email content

Not sure if I am doing this in right way or any other way to grab the id once the email is read.

Comment: You're on the right track... of course you will need `http://yourserver.com/getId.php` instead of `getId.php`, but this all seems fine. If they are using a text-based email program the image will never be downloaded, and they can opt to not download images. Also, gmail now downloads the image immediately after it hits their servers, so it will be a false positive.

Comment: Simply don't spy on people this way. If you want to know when someone did read the msg, send them a link to your server with the mail contents instead of putting the text into the mail. But don't spy. -1 for spying.
It's not your business to collect informatino about when I read my mails. If I get a mail from a job I applied with such tracking image, I'd send them to hell and cancel the application before they even can answer the application.

Comment: Sorry but to some extent I can't agree with you any more and thanks for not liking my ques.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the most common method, though not 100% accurate. Most emailclients block external images. If your candidate doesn't allow them, you never know if they've opened the email.

Best way to ensure it, is creating an email in a way that they would download the images. You could think of a logo or some other layout elements.

Besides that, your `img src` should be a full URL: `<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/getId.php?id=[%candidate_ID%]">`, so you can track it on the server side.

There isn't a 100% accurate way to do this, mainly because of difference in mailclients. If you want to be absolutly sure, you must let the candidate click on a link in the email to confirm they've read it.